# Problems setting APP name in Datadog logs with Heroku Private Space Logging

Tags: heroku, logging, datadog

I'm trying to name the service for my apps that use spaces and Private Space Logging. I configured the APPNAME, DD_SERVICE, HEROKU_APP_NAME variable and still the service appears as Heroku and the Host as the App ID. When the APP is outside the Space, I just need to add the Log Drain and change the name of the Service and Host and it works, as per the example: heroku drains:add "https://http-intake.logs.datadoghq.com/api/v2/logs?dd-api-key=<DD_API_KEY>&ddsource=heroku&env=&service= &host=" -a <APPLICATION_NAME>

In the Space settings, it is configured like this:

https://http-intake.logs.datadoghq.com/api/v2/logs/?dd-api-key=<DD_API_KEY>&ddsource=heroku

I'm forgetting something? I searched and unfortunately I didn't find anything in the Heroku and Datadog documentation.

Expected:

That Datadog logs show both the Service and Host fields as the name of the Heroku APP and not the app ID.